# How to ALWAYS keep the Search button next to the input bar when resizing using %

Tags: css

I have been attempting to solve this phenomina using style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;". The search button still appears at the bottom left and creates an "l" shape. If any has ideas as to why this happens it would help

```css
#searchbartop{
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:25%;
       
}

#searchbartoptext{
    width:600%;
}
```

```html
<form id="searchbartop">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="searchbartoptext" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;" required>
                <input type="button" style="width: auto;" value="Search">
            </form>
```

Comment: hey, you have given width as 600%!!

Comment: Are you able to see the bar in the "Run code snippet" section?

Comment: which bar, i can see a text-box and a button in the next line

Comment: Do you need like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bkzvk7b6/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkzvk7b6/)**

```
#searchbartop {
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left:25%;
    width:75%;
}
#searchbartop input[type=text] {
    width:70%;
    padding-right: .5em;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
#searchbartop input[type=button] {
    width:20%;
    display:block;
     float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="searchbartop">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." required/>
    <input type="button" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, Now i have to deal with invisible margins blocking buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the search button to `position:absolute;` as is the case in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww17ykhk/)